# Nginx: How to reverse proxy from external request to specific localhost url

Tags: java, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

In server I have a application that responding with specific url (http://localhost:8080/bookList). I want a specific url of this server to be proxied by nginx from external request.

I run this app with using maven with below commands in shell (firstly build and  then running)

```
mvn clean install -B
mvn spring-boot:run
```

When I execute this command in server which apps running by shell it respond correct ;

```
curl http://localhost:8080/bookList
```

Here is the my nginx config;

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  server {

        listen 80;
        server_name 10.10.10.10;


           location /bookList {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/bookList/;
           proxy_redirect  off;
           proxy_buffer_size 128k;
           proxy_buffers 4 256k;
           proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;


           }
    }

}
```

But when I try with browser with url  (http://10.10.10.10/bookList) from external I see below fault which is 502 Bad Gateway

[image]

Comment: Change `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/bookList/;` to `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;`

Comment: It does not work still.

Comment: Any error log entries?

Comment: I solved the issue by disabled selinux.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related by selinux and solved with below commands;

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setenforce 0
```

Here is the links which explain how to modify selinux to setup nginx reverse proxy

[Using NGINX and NGINX Plus with SELinux](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/)

[Setting up reverse proxies with NGINX](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/setting-reverse-proxies-nginx)

I guess that need to make sure some of the permissions arranged as appropirate, ıf using Nginx which accept request externaly